# PHP Generated Navigation assign a class to active page

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to assign a `class='active'` to the page your viewing on the moment.
My menu is generated with PHP from an array, see the code bellow:

```
<?php
    $navmenu = array(
        'index' => 'Home',
        'about' => 'About',
        'page3' => 'Page3',
        'page4' => 'Page4',
        'page5' => 'Page5',
        'page6' => 'Page6'
    );
?>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <?php
            foreach ($navmenu as $url => $diplay) {
                echo "<li><a href='{$url}.php' class=''>{$diplay}</a></li>\n";
            }
        ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I would like to add class='active' to the page you'r viewing at the moment, but I have no idea how to do that, in simple HTML will be like this:

```
<li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
<li><a href="page3.html">Page3</a></li>
<li><a href="page3.html">Page4</a></li>
<li><a href="page3.html">Page5</a></li>
<li><a href="page3.html">Page6</a></li>
```

Let me know, what options I have to implement this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just compare if your current URL (stored in $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] is part of the url you are about to print and in this case add class="active" to your output.

Remember that this solution can have trouble if you have urls that contain the same name parts such as "index" and "profile_index_page" would generate a false positive.

For a 100% solution to this problem you need to use alot of regex or create a little router with predefined routes.

Also this solution is very static as you lack the ability to add any custom html attributes for later purposes but I dont want to go too far here, you will know if this solution fits your requirements.

```
$output = "";
foreach ($navmenu as $url => $diplay) {
    $output .= '<li><a ';
    if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $url) !== false) {
        $output .= 'class="active" ';
    } 
    $output .= '>' .$diplay . '</a></li>\n';
}
echo $output;
```

Comment: this worked well for me, only the `$output` variable with `class="active"` you used it for `<a>` tag, but I changed it for `<li>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

One Option would be to read the URL and compare it in the `foreach` loop.

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```

That will get you the URL portion you need.

Then you just compare that in your `foreach` loop.

```
foreach ($navmenu as $url => $diplay) {
    $addClass = "";
    $urlArray = explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    $urlArraySize = sizeof($urlArray);

    if($urlArray[$urlArraySize - 1] == $url."php")
    {
        $addClass = ' class="active"';
    }

    echo "<li".$addClass."><a href='{$url}.php' class=''>{$diplay}</a></li>\n";
}
```

**NOTE:** This has a couple more steps than needed, but it does an *exact* comparison to the last value (which is your page value) in the URL. This will not account for any parameters passed via the URL.